# Passing useState as props in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-props

Say I have a parent component with two child components:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [myVar, setmyVar] = useState(false)

   return (
     <>
       <MyChildComponent1 myVar={myVar} setMyVar={setMyVar} \> 
       <MyChildComponent2 myVar={myVar} \>
     </>
   )
}
```

Now how would I go about setting the type correctly in `MyChildComponent2`?

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
const MyChildComponent1 = (
  {myVar, setMyVar}: 
  {myVar: boolean, setMyVar: (value: boolean) => void}) = (...)
```

Is the type for `setMyvar` correct? Or should it be something else?

Comment: Clearer answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59261671/how-do-i-change-props-from-a-child-component-using-hooks/

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The type that would match the function returned from invoking `useState` would be:

```
setMyVar: (value: boolean | ((prevVar: boolean) => boolean)) => void;
```

If we look at the type definition file from `DefinitelyTyped` [1], we can see that the second type in the return type is a dispatch:

```
function useState<S>(initialState: S | (() => S)): [S, Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>];
```

Thus the generic type provided is passed through to `SetStateAction<S>`, which is defined as:

```
type SetStateAction<S> = S | ((prevState: S) => S);
```

So essentially, an interface for your component would be the following:

```
interface IProps {
  myVar: boolean;
  setMyVar?: (value: boolean | (prevVar: boolean) => boolean) => void;
}
```

As @Retsam said, it's best to use React's exported types:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

interface IProps {
  myVar: boolean;
  setMyVar?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}
```

References:
[1] https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L845

Comment: They can import the `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction<S>` types from React, so their types could be `{myVar: boolean, setMyVar?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>}`

Comment: @Retsam, consoder writing this as an answer instead of a comment. I'm new to typescript and react and hooks -- too much moving parts at the same time. Any drawbacks to this approach?

Comment: yes, thank you @Retsam... TS stopped screaming at me and removed 10 warnings

Comment: This is gold! Thank you 

Comment: What about making it even shorter? `{myVar: boolean, setMyVar?: Dispatch<boolean>}`

Comment: I love the thorough explanation here. Bravo!

Answer (score 31):

### Dispatch & SetStateAction types

As @Retsam mentioned, you can also import and use the types `Dispatch` and `SetStateAction` from React:

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

const MyChildComponent1 = (
  myVar: boolean,
  setMyVar: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>
) => {...};
```

---

#### Bonus

When I find myself frequently using this, I create a type alias to help with readability

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

type Dispatcher<S> = Dispatch<SetStateAction<S>>;

const MyChildComponent1 = (
  myVar: boolean,
  setMyVar: Dispatcher<boolean>,
) => {...};
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Very cool answer, I like this implementation

Comment: Very clean code and I have implemented it in my app.

Comment: Is it possible to use Dispatch, SetStateAction with PropType's InferProps?

Answer (score 5):

Adding onto @fiz's comment, his code of block was slightly not working for me:

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from 'react';

const MyChildComponent1 = (
  myVar: boolean,
  setMyVar: Dispatch<SetStateAction<<boolean>>
) => {...};
```

I had to set `setMyVar: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>` (there was one too many brackets)

Comment: Thanks for correcting the syntax error. Btw, you can edit the answer next time for small errors like this or other marginal improvements, instead of creating an entire other post. Welcome to the community!

Answer (score 4):

It can also be done like this using Interface and React components.

***MainComponent.tsx***

> Value assignment of the useState component defined in Main is done in
> the child component. When this field is triggered, the code in useEffect will run.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import Login from './views/Login/index';

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setAuthenticatedStatus] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isAuthenticated)
            window.location.href = "<redirect url>";
    }, [isAuthenticated]);

    return (<Login setLoginStatus={setAuthenticatedStatus} />)
};

export default App;
```

***ChildComponent.tsx***

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction, FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import authService from '../../apiServices/authService';

interface IProps {
   setLoginStatus: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const Login: FunctionComponent<IProps> = (props: IProps) => {

   const login = async (username: string, password: string) => {
      const response = await authService.authenticateUser(username, password);

      if (response && response.statusCode == 200 && response.result.accessToken) {
         props.setLoginStatus(true);
      }
      else {
         // ...
      }
   };


   return (
      <>
         ...
      </>
   );
};

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the other answers slightly confusing, so here's what worked for me:

Instantiate useState() in parent.ts:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState<stateType>(initialState)
```

Pass in setSomeState() to child.ts:

```
<Child
    setSomeState={setSomeState}
/>
```

*Make sure to only pass the name without the ()*

In child.ts set Props like so:

```
import Dispatch from 'react'

interface Props {setSomeState: Dispatch<stateType>}
```

Answer (score 0):

**MyChildComponent1.tsx** 
set type Props like this:

import React from 'react' 

type Props = { 
myVar:boolean; 
setmyVar: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction*`<boolean>`*>;

}

const MyChildComponent = ({myVar, setmyVar}: Props) => { 

... YOUR CODE ...

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76731499/637889) on another question. which obtains the `useState` return type, the child component prop types can just be declared as the first and second items of this `ReturnType`

```
type UseStateHook = ReturnType<typeof useState<boolean>>

const MyChildComponent1 = (
    myVar: UseStateHook[0]
    setMyVar: UseStateHook[1]
) => {...};
```