# How do I change props from a child component using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'd like to change the props using react hooks, and I found the way passing setState function as props to the child.

**Container.tsx**

```
const Container: React.FC = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  return <Counter num={num} setNum={setNum} />;

};
```

**Counter.tsx**

```
interface CounterProps {
  num: number;
  setNum: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

const Counter: React.FC<CounterProps> = ({ num, setNum }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };

  return (
    // jsx codes...
  );
};
```

It works well, but I have to add two props to the child component per one state of the parent. Is there a more efficient way for this problem?

Comment: I think there is no problem using two props like that. This looks clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the correct way of doing it. There are two ways of condensing this if needed.

First is to just pass a tuple instead of two separate props.

```
const Container: React.FC = () => {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0);
  return <Counter numState={[num, setNum]} />
};

interface CounterProps {
  numState: [number, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>];
}

const Counter: React.FC<CounterProps> = ({ numState: [num, setNum] }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    setNum(num + 1);
  };
};
```

or do it more cleanly by passing an object with the keys 'state' and 'setter' or something similar.

Secondly, if you find that you're using this sort of thing a lot, then you might want to invest some time into setting up a global state management system like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/).

Comment: I think you can make it even shorter: `numState: [number, React.Dispatch<number>]`

Answer (score 1):

This can be simplified even further now, since TypeScript 2.8 added [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype), by obtaining the return type of the `useState` hook.

```
interface CounterProps {
    numState: ReturnType<typeof useState<number>>
}

const Counter = ({ numState: [num, setNum] }: CounterProps) => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        setNum(num + 1)
    }
}
```