# How to pass const value from one react js file to another?

Tags: reactjs, constants

I am a little new on react. How can I pass a variable with its value from one react js file to another?

File A.js:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(35)
```

File B.js:

```
import value from "./A.js"
console.log(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to export it either as a default or a regular export.

Try the following:

```
export const ...
```

or:

```
export default const ...
```

Comment: When I write export const, error says: Modifiers cannot appear here.ts(1184)

Comment: And when I write outside of my main component(top-level comp), I mean: "export const [value, setValue] = useState("10")"  error comes: "invalid hood call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function..." error. It seems I cannot use useState outside of my main comp

Comment: You can pass setState as a prop to a child component. You can't export it.

Comment: so how can I export a "variable" to a different file? Probably using useState since it is a variable.

Comment: Where do you need this variable? This is how you pass state as a prop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56028635/passing-usestate-as-props-in-typescript

Comment: I am now trying to understand it. I didn't think exporting a variable is such complicated.

Comment: meanwhile, I don't need to update the value in the B file, I will just use the state of it in A file

Answer (score 0):

In file a.js // source file

Add this:

```js
export const endpoint_val = 'value of endpoint';
```

Go to file b.js

```js
import { endpoint_val } from './a.js'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get ... does not contain a default export ...